# Adding Computer to Multiple Active Directory Groups During Task Sequence Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sccm

I'm trying to set up my task sequence for SCCM to automatically add laptops to 3 Active Directory groups. I've set up a step to do this and am calling upon a Powershell script to do so. The script should be run as a network admin so I don't believe I'm having any issues with authorization however I am super new to Powershell so I believe my issue is with my syntax. My script is simple enough and all of the resources I look at seem to overcomplicate Powershell for what I need to do. Here is my script:

```
ADD-ADGroupMember "GroupOne" -members "$env:computername$"
ADD-ADGroupMember "GroupTwo" -members "$env:computername$"
ADD-ADGroupMember "GroupThree" -members "$env:computername$"
```

The $env:computername is supposed to automatically gather the computer's name which is established earlier in the task sequence and the $ following it is required to add using powershell, I've found.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: I've got it working finally, below is the code I've found and used for one of the powershell scripts -

```
 $ComputerName = gc env:computername

 $isMember = new-object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"")
 $ismember.filter = “(&(objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName=$Computername$)(memberof=CN=<CN NAME>,OU=<OU NAME>,DC=<DC NAME>,DC=<DC NAME>))”
 $isMemberResult = $isMember.FindOne()

 If ($isMemberResult) {exit}

 else
{
   $searcher = new-object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"")
   $searcher.filter = “(&(objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName= $Computername$))”
   $FoundComputer = $searcher.FindOne()
   $P = $FoundComputer | select path
   $ComputerPath = $p.path
   $GroupPath = "LDAP://CN=<CN NAME>,OU=<OU NAME>,DC=<DC NAME>,DC=<DC NAME>"
   $Group = [ADSI]"$GroupPath"
   $Group.Add("$ComputerPath")
   $Group.SetInfo()
}
```

Comment: One thought is that `Add-ADGroupMember` is a AD cmdlet installed with RSAT. Does the machine that is running this have RSAT installed so that it has the AD Cmdlets?

Comment: I would recommend updating the question to include any error messages you have received; without that, we can't be sure that you're correct about your problem being 'syntax'.

Comment: @BenH I thought that this was already a part of the package but it actually looks like it wasn't. So right now I'm working on running a script that doesn't use AD cmdlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to compose the computer's account name from an environment variable, and then using that to add to the group, simply get the computer object from Active Directory:

```
$Computer = Get-ADComputer -Identity $env:ComputerName
foreach ($Group in @("GroupOne", "GroupTwo", "GroupThree")) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $Computer
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a computer booting up now. I'll let you know if I'm successful!

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

Turns out the user that was "running" my scripts did not have sufficient access to add a computer to AD OUs. I also did not have the AD cmdlets in the package associated with the step. What I did instead was I ran a bat file which contained:

     powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "%~dp0addToGroup1.ps1"
     powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "%~dp0addToGroup2.ps1" 
     powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "%~dp0addToGroup3.ps1"

The ~dp0 portion evidently is used with the execution policy to ensure that the file is being pulled --

Comment: -- from the "current" directory (where my powershell scripts were located).

My powershell script will have to be added as an answer so look on this page for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you didn't have the AD cmdlets available. Here's how you could do it with ADSI:

```
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(cn=$env:COMPUTERNAME))"
$ComputerDN = ([adsisearcher]$filter).FindOne().Properties.distinguishedname

$GroupName = "GroupOne"
$filter = "(&(objectClass=Group)(cn=$GroupName))"
$GroupDN = ([adsisearcher]$filter).FindOne().Properties.distinguishedname
$Group = [adsi]"LDAP://$GroupDN"

$Group.Add($ComputerDN)

$GroupName = "GroupTwo"
$filter = "(&(objectClass=Group)(cn=$GroupName))"
$GroupDN = ([adsisearcher]$filter).FindOne().Properties.distinguishedname
$Group = [adsi]"LDAP://$GroupDN"

$Group.Add($ComputerDN)

$GroupName = "GroupThree"
$filter = "(&(objectClass=Group)(cn=$GroupName))"
$GroupDN = ([adsisearcher]$filter).FindOne().Properties.distinguishedname
$Group = [adsi]"LDAP://$GroupDN"

$Group.Add($ComputerDN)
```

If you have any more groups, it would probably worth turning into a function.

Just make sure that whatever user context is running this has rights to add members to that group.